# save seekbar progress between activity transitions

Tags: android, android-seekbar

EDIT:I have solved the problem myself.Anyone need the solution please ping me.

I have searched all over the net and StackOverflow but in vain.
I am making a music app which contains a seekbar.
The first activity shows the list of albums and when you click any album you get the list of songs in the second activity. Clicking the song plays the file and seek bar progresses. Fine till here!

But when I go back to album activity and then again to song Activity (by clicking any album) the seekbar  gets sets at the end automatically.

I tried setting the onResume method of Song Activity Like this

protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

```
    if(MyMediaPlayerService.mPlayer!=null && MyMediaPlayerService.mPlayer.isPlaying())
        seek_Bar.setProgress(MyMediaPlayerService.mPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
```

}

And I also tried using share preference But i don't think I need that.

Please help me in this and please tell me if you need extra information to solve my problem.

Comment: tried to Log.d MyMediaPlayerService.mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() ?

Comment: in the place you are using it

Comment: @pskink as you said I printed it in the onStop and onResume method of the activity. It's printing the correct values.

Comment: what is a max ProgressBar's value?

Comment: @pskink i have set it Songlist.seek_Bar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());

Comment: Log.d the max value and the value you are setting

Comment: @pskink I have not enough credits to comment more could you share your id so that i can chat and share my problem with you

Comment: can anyone help me on this

Comment: i already said: Log.d the max value and the value you are setting

Comment: You aint getting my problem dude everythings printing fine but the seekbar is getting set automatically at the end.

Comment: it cannot be set "automatically", there is no magic...

Comment: I have solved the problem so if anyone wants to know the solution please comment and I will be happy to help you.